# HBase Schema design for parametric search

Tags: hbase

I am designing an application where users can search historical sales data by laptop parameters.

Lets use laptops for example, a laptop has the attribute like 'RAM', 'CPU', 'MANUFACTURER', 'MODEL', 'DISKTYPE'..etc.

See the picture below to have a feeling how the front end should look like, so I have two questions here:

1. I am planning to use HBase so I have a platform that scales well. However, I am having a hard time designing the proper schema for the data I have. This is the schema that I am envisioning:

   ```
   rowkey: transaction_id 
   column_family1: parametrics:
   qualifier1: brand
   qualifier2: memory 
   qualifier3: disk_type
   qualifier4: transation_date
   ....
   ```
2. The dropdown list should only contain all the distinct value that ever exist in the database, i.e., if we only have 2GB and 4GB laptops in the database, user should never have the option of other values other than 2 or 4, the other filters should work in the same way. Does that mean whenever a user opens the page, I have to loop through the whole database to grab the distinct values?

This is a mock up:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are depending only on hbase table to get the reference data of two fields, to display on web page, then may be it more to do with overall design and not just hbase design. There is no link in hbase things, like a foreign key stuff, but just like any other rdbms stuff, you can run the distinct once and store it in cache, to retrieve and display on frontend. HBase works for low latency, but i will still think again to depend solely on Hbase, to give you drop down values. Even i will wait for an answer, to this question. happy Designing.

Answer (score 0):

Would you run `SELECT DISTINCT(category) FROM transactions` using a relational database every time you render the search form? Probably not. You would normalize the schema by having a Category Table, a Channel Table etc. I would recommend the same approach with HBase except that you would either have to implement referential integrity and JOINs at the application level or using something like Phoenix.